# cannot get deepwater to run on MBP with TF

Tags: tensorflow, h2o

I am trying to run to get R + deepwater + tensorflow to work on a MBP.

The following have been installed.

```
Python 3.6.1
TensorFlow 1.1
```

The `Hello, TensorFlow` example on the TensorFlow website is working fine.

```
R version 3.4.0

curl -O http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3904/R/src/contrib/h2o_3.11.0.3904.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL h2o_3.11.0.3904.tar.gz

curl -O http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-deepwater/public/nightly/latest/h2o_3.11.0.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL h2o_3.11.0.tar.gz
```

I am trying run the following example provided on the h2o website.

```
require(h2o)

h2o.init()

train <- h2o.importFile("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz")

target <- "C785"
features <- setdiff(names(train), target)

train[target] <- as.factor(train[target])

model <- h2o.deepwater(x=features, y=target, training_frame=train, epochs=100, activation="Rectifier",
    hidden=c(200,200), ignore_const_cols=FALSE, mini_batch_size=256, input_dropout_ratio=0.1, 
    hidden_dropout_ratios=c(0.5,0.5), stopping_rounds=3, stopping_tolerance=0.05, 
    stopping_metric="misclassification", score_interval=2, score_duty_cycle=0.5, score_training_samples=1000, 
    score_validation_samples=1000, nfolds=5, gpu=FALSE, seed=1234, backend="tensorflow")
```

The error I get is `Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize backend: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: darwin, architecture: x86_64.`  Based on what I read on SO and the git page, I was under the impression that one does not need to build for the Mac platform.

One other thing that I tried was to use the info from https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow.  When I run `install_tensorflow()` I get `Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available.`  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide H2O+deepwater builds for MacOS. The one you downloaded is built for Linux machines (tested on Ubuntu), it's mentioned [on the download page](https://www.h2o.ai/download/).

If you want to run it on MacOS you'd have to build both [DeepWater](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#diy-build-instructions) and then [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3#Building) yourself.

Comment: My apologies.  Would those bits work for RHEL6 x64 or is it specific for Ubuntu only?

Comment: We haven't tested it on RHEL6 but I'd say yes, it should work out of the box.

Comment: I am about to give it a spin.  I think need to install the parts which are *above* the example in the original post.   Do I need to do the `install_tensorflow()`?

Comment: @ironv you don't need `rstudio/tensorflow` to run DeepWater, unless you want to create custom TF graphs first. We provide several networks out of the box (MLP, lenet, alexnet, restnet, vgg etc.).